# 2D Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to calculate the 2D Fourier transformation of a circular shaped aperture, but *Mathematica* won't finish the calculation:

```
h[x_, y_] := UnitBox[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]
Plot3D[FourierTransform[h[x, y], {x, y}, {k1, k2}], {k1, -5, 5}, {k2, -5, 5}]
```

So I tried to use the numerical `NFourierTransform`, but it showed me just an empty plot.

```
Needs["FourierSeries`"]
Plot3D[NFourierTransform[h[x, y], {x, y}, {k1, k2}], 
  {k1, -3, 3}, {k2, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Does somebody know how I can calculate the Fourier transform of a circular aperture in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: what is the definition of `h[]` ?

Comment: Sorry, I tried different versions of the UnitBox and forgot to change the function. I edited my Question.

Comment: Presumably there are some imaginary numbers in the result which is why you get an empty image. Either take `Abs` of the Fourier transform, or look at the real and imaginary parts separately. You could also create an image of the aperture `ap=Table[h[i,j],{i,-5,5,10/99},{j,-5,5,10/99}]` and do the discrete transform `ArrayPlot[Abs@Fourier@ap]` or something.

Comment: The reason why `NFourierTransform` gives you an empty box is that it can only handle one-dimensional integrals. For a more robust numerical approach, you may want to look at [2D Fourier transform of a few (4) disjoint discs on a plane](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63045/245)

Answer (score 6):

To get the correct result for the 2D Fourier transform of a function which doesn't factor in Cartesian coordinates, it's usually necessary to give *Mathematica* some assistance as to the best choice of coordinates.

In the circular case, that of course means we should use polar coordinates:

```
Clear[k];
airy[k_] = 
 1/(2 Pi)
   Integrate[
   r Exp[I k r Cos[ϕ]], {r, 0, 1}, {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}]

(* ==> BesselJ[1, k]/k *)

Plot[airy[k], {k, -40, 40}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: airy]

This is the famous [Airy diffraction pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk) of a circular aperture (when squared to get the intensity).

In setting up the integral for the Fourier transform, I used the fact that the expected result will depend only on the magnitude and not on the direction of the wave vector, so that you can choose the direction of $\vec{k}$ as the `x` axis for the polar integral.

Comment: +1 I deleted my answer.You're right, of course (I forgot the Jacobian)